# php hyperlinks formatting issue

Tags: php

I have the hyperlinks displayed using php as

```
<a href="<?php echo $object->property; ?>"><?php echo $object->property; ?></a>
```

The $object-> property returns results on multiple lines separated by semicolon

How can  i get the results to get displayed without the semicolon

Comment: it'd be helpful to see a sample of `$object->property`'s output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can user [str_replace](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo str_replace(';', '', $object->property);
```